# Non English Stack Overflow-like sites

Tags: discussion, internationalization, crowdsourcing

What sites are there, similar to Stack Overflow, but in different languages?

By this I mean:

- Public programming Q&A sites and communities
- Not in the Stack Exchange network
- With original content (not SCRAPERs)
- Not in English

We often find these sites have great ideas and great communities. Looking at them helps us serve you better!

Some examples: http://segmentfault.com/, http://entredesarrolladores.com/, https://teratail.com/...

Comment: So tempted to close... *This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network.* Can you explain why you posted this here?

Comment: *Public programming Q&A sites and communities*, you mean those respecting the Q/A format, or does MSDN qualify too?

Comment: @PatrickHofman we learn from other sites in order to build "the software that powers the Stack Exchange network", so yep, it belongs here IMO. We're mostly interested in non English stuff.

Comment: @Pat request here is for sites with overall design close to SE sites, mainly voting system, reputation, etc. All the old school forums don't fit into this, of course.

Comment: It seems "programming ... communities" are allowed too, so that would make it overly broad. @Sha

Comment: @Pat "similar to Stack Overflow" is the first criteria. :)

Comment: @Sklivvz Wouldn't this get better attention on Meta Stack Overflow anyways?

Comment: _"Not in the Stack Exchange network"_ - why? What's wrong with local SO sites? By the way they do have their own rules :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Because Stack Exchange employees are already aware of the existence of Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @zaq, didn't look into his profile. So this question is about other sites absorbtion, like it was with hashcode?

Comment: @Qwertiy not really. It's about research, these sites typically look at us and solve a local problem. We want to look at them and see what we could be doing better.

Answer (score 6):

There's a Polish Stack Overflow-like site [forum.pasja-informatyki.pl](http://forum.pasja-informatyki.pl/). It uses [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) platform. Some stats:

- 24K questions
- 55K answers
- 99K comments
- 11K users

It's the only major Polish programming community that I know of that uses a Q&A system. There are, however, many forums:

- [forum.php.pl](http://forum.php.pl/): a forum focused on PHP and related technologies (JavaScript, HTML, CSS, MySQL), 1.2M posts
- [forum.4programmers.net](http://forum.4programmers.net/): 1M posts
- [www.forumweb.pl](http://www.forumweb.pl/): a forum for web developers, 400K posts
- [www.coderscity.pl](http://www.coderscity.pl/): 198K posts
- [cpp0x.pl](http://cpp0x.pl/forum/): a forum focused on C and C++, 142K posts

Comment: Polish PHP programmers?  There's gotta be a joke in there somewhere...

Comment: @Won't What do you mean?

Comment: I dunno.  Something deep inside me is screaming for a joke, but I just can't...

Comment: And also, there is a Vietnamese site that I think is stealing content from us.

Answer (score 3):

Hebrew Q&A programming site: https://safot.cs.technion.ac.il/ which is an internal Q&A site of a [major Israeli University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technion_%E2%80%93_Israel_Institute_of_Technology) and intended for their own contents, also using [Q2A](http://www.question2answer.org/) platform.

It contains some nice design ideas not present in Stack Exchange, e.g. Top Contributors and Site Status in their homepage.